# Nginx + PHP-FPM URI alias and multiple php directories

Tags: nginx, php, web-server, php-fpm

I am trying to configure Nginx to host multiple PHP based apps in two different directories in the same domain. The outcome I'm trying to get to is:

http://webserver.local/  > app served from `/path/to/website`

http://webserver.local/app  > app served from `/path/to/php-app`

Here is the configuration I have.

- Everything works (being PHP and non-PHP resources) when I hit http://webserver.local/.
- However, PHP scripts are not working when I go to http://webserver.local/app/index.php. I get `File Not Found` (however, file is there at `/path/to/php-app/index.php`).
- I created a file `/path/to/php-app/test.txt` (something not PHP), and when I go to http://webserver.local/app/test.txt, I get the text file as expected.

Can someone please shed some light as to where I am going wrong? Thanks :)

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  webserver.local;

    location / {
        root   /path/to/website;
        index  index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /path/to/website;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location ^~ /app {
        alias   /path/to/php-app;
        index  index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /path/to/php-app;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your nested `location ~ \.php$` block will not find your PHP scripts. The `$document_root` is set to `/path/to/php-app`. And `$fastcgi_script_name` is the same as `$uri` which still includes the `/app` prefix.

The correct approach is to use `$request_filename` and remove your bogus `root` statement:

```
location ^~ /app {
    alias   /path/to/php-app;
    index  index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

Always include `fastcgi_params` before any `fastcgi_param` statements to avoid them being silently overwritten by the contents of the include file. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_filename) for details.