# nginx location without initial path component

Tags: nginx

I have a location block that looks something like this:

```
root /var/www/ProjectP;

location /p/ {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ /p/.*\.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

In order to make that work, I created a directory `/var/www/ProjectP/p/`, which is a horrible hack, because it puts the knowledge of where in http space the project is served with the project and not with nginx.  Nginx config should be able to move it to `/pp/` without modifying project P.

This particular project doesn't have a `proxy_pass` directive, but that will happen next, and then my hack is quite unlikely to work.

I'm sure nginx has a correct way to handle something so common, but I've not found it.  Any pointers?

### Update 1

As @RichardSmith notes, the right approach is surely an [alias](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directive.  Testing this on static content works nicely:

```
location /a/ {
    alias /var/www/ProjectA/;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

When I do the same with the php code, I get half success:

```
location /p/ {
    alias /var/www/ProjectP/;
    index index.php;

    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
location ~ /p/(.+\.php)$ {
    alias /var/www/ProjectP/$1;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    # With php7.0-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    ## These next are largely set via snippets/fastcgi-php.conf.
    ## Trying them here doesn't help, but I leave them (commented out)
    ## for the moment...
    #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    #include fastcgi_params;
    #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $uri;
}
```

Testing against a non-php file, I confirm that the first block works.  But the second block does not, and so php files don't serve properly.  (I get 404's.)  I've tried a few variants on the commented-out fastcgi directives at the end, but clearly not the right combination.

### Update 2

This works.

```
root /var/www/;

location /p/ {
    alias /var/www/ProjectP/;
    index index.php;

    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    # Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use an `alias` statement. Something like [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/876332/nginx-php-fpm-uri-alias-and-multiple-php-directories/876349#876349)

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks, I think that's the right approach. And after some reading and fiddling, it yields progress, but not quite success.  I've amended the question to show what I've tried.

Comment: @RichardSmith Now that I got it working, I see that you were 100% right and I had mistyped (mis-copied) the solution presented in that link.  *Sigh*.

Comment: My only suggestion is to remove your `try_files` statement which is default `nginx` behaviour anyway. `try_files` and `alias` can be a troublesome together, see [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
root /var/www/;

location /p/ {
    alias /var/www/ProjectP/;
    index index.php;

    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    # Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one issue with your `location` block.

If you request `http://www.example.com/p/test.php`, the contents of `$1` variable will be `test.php`.

This means your

```
alias /var/www/ProjectP/$1;
```

will make the document root directory to `/var/www/ProjectP/test.php`.

Then, the

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

defines the actual filepath sent to PHP process to locate the file. `$document_root` contains the `alias` path in this cast, and `$fastcgi_script_name` contains the filename from the request.

So, the end result in your case, that the request to `http://www.example.com/p/test.php` ends up to a filename `/var/www/ProjectP/test.phptest.php` for PHP process. Therefore there will be a `404` returned.

The fix is to just use:

```
alias /var/www/ProjectP
```

in the PHP `location` block.

Comment: That makes sense, but doesn't fix the problem.  I'm not sure why.  I also tried specifying `$document_root` and `$request_filename`.  But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28494798/833300) sorted the problem.  I'm not 100% sure why they are different.  Here the php location block is nested in the outer block.

Comment: Cf. update 2, above, for what the successful block looks like.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer yourself and accept it and remove the update from the question.